# AWS Lake Formation : grant_permissions : Unknown parameter in Resource.Table: "TableWildcard"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-lake-formation

Trying to grant lake permissions via a Lambda Function. (Python 3.8)
As far as I can see, I have my code as per documentation.
Yet hitting a barrage of nonsense errors about parameters being incorrect.
Could it be that I just need an optician ?
Or is it some nuance or  which way the Amazon wind blows today ?

```
import boto3
import json
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def main(event,context):

    client = boto3.client('lakeformation')

    response = client.grant_permissions(
        Principal={
            'DataLakePrincipalIdentifier': 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/myRole'
        },
        Resource={
            'Table': {
                'DatabaseName': 'myDatabase',
                'TableWildcard': {}
            },
        },
        Permissions=['ALL'],
        PermissionsWithGrantOption=['ALL']
    )
```

======================================================================================

> [ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Missing
> required parameter in Resource.Table: "Name" Unknown parameter in
> Resource.Table: "TableWildcard", must be one of: DatabaseName, Name
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/main.py", line
> 10, in main
> response = client.grant_permissions(   File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
> return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 607, in _make_api_call
> request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(   File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 655, in
> _convert_to_request_dict
> request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(   File "/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py", line 297, in serialize_to_request
> raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())

Comment: What version of boto3 are you using? Is it the latest one?

Comment: Sorry, it's running as a lambda which is set to Python 3.8

Comment: It seems to be a lambda issue. I have the same error on lambda. But it works on local workstation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated the issue a bit. And the error is because on lambda, the definition of `TableResoures` is (note the missing `TableWildcard` on lambda):

```
    "TableResource":{
      "type":"structure",
      "required":[
        "DatabaseName",
        "Name"
      ],
      "members":{
        "DatabaseName":{
          "shape":"NameString",
          "documentation":"<p>The name of the database for the table. Unique to a Data Catalog. A database is a set of associated table definitions organized into a logical group. You can Grant and Revoke database privileges to a principal. </p>"
        },
        "Name":{
          "shape":"NameString",
          "documentation":"<p>The name of the table.</p>"
        }
      },
      "documentation":"<p>A structure for the table object. A table is a metadata definition that represents your data. You can Grant and Revoke table privileges to a principal. </p>"
    }
```

In contrast, the [latest version on github](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/data/lakeformation/2017-03-31/service-2.json) has:

```
    "TableResource":{
      "type":"structure",
      "required":["DatabaseName"],
      "members":{
        "CatalogId":{
          "shape":"CatalogIdString",
          "documentation":"<p>The identifier for the Data Catalog. By default, it is the account ID of the caller.</p>"
        },
        "DatabaseName":{
          "shape":"NameString",
          "documentation":"<p>The name of the database for the table. Unique to a Data Catalog. A database is a set of associated table definitions organized into a logical group. You can Grant and Revoke database privileges to a principal. </p>"
        },
        "Name":{
          "shape":"NameString",
          "documentation":"<p>The name of the table.</p>"
        },
        "TableWildcard":{
          "shape":"TableWildcard",
          "documentation":"<p>A wildcard object representing every table under a database.</p> <p>At least one of <code>TableResource$Name</code> or <code>TableResource$TableWildcard</code> is required.</p>"
        }
      }
```

Seems to me that this is some bug.

Comment: Aha ! So the Vsn of Boto on Lambda is not recent enough for the API.  Given that, I found an article on how to add a new vsn of Boto into Lambda as a layer. All I need to do now is to find a Windows version of these instructions ;) https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-runtime-errors/

Comment: @SimonB Let me know how it will go. Layer would be good workaround for the issue.